# Возможно ли держать данные MongoDB в RAM?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ram

Привет. Хотел узнать, можно ли выгрузить все данные mongoDB в память и работать там с ними?

Comment: не совсем понял вопроса - без синхронизации с жестким диском что-ли?

Другими словами - какую цель вы преследуете?

Comment: Наоборот. Я хочу держать полностью все данные в RAM и реплицировать их с определённым промежутком времени.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно.

Для начала отметим, что монга и так хранит часто используемые данные в памяти, а неиспользуемые дампит на диск. 
За переодичность этого дампа отвечает параметр [syncdelay](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/--syncdelay)

Если запустить монгу с syncdelay = 0, то данные никогда не будут дампиться на диск, а всегда будут находится в памяти.

Comment: А можно сделать, чтобы именно все данные были в RAM, а не часть, но все-же дампить с определенной частотой?

Comment: А что Вы хотите-то на самом деле в итоге получить, расскажите? Если Вам нужны бэкапы, держите всё в памяти и запускайте mongodump, когда хотите. Если нужны реплики - в монге есть возможность настроить master-slave отношения.